# It is necessary to make several separate variables from a string

Tags: perl

How to get three separate variables from a string?
my $string = '2019-08-20';
my ($year, $month, $day);

Comment: `split /-/, $string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my  $string = '2019-08-20';
my ($year, $month, $day) = $string =~ /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/;

if( defined($day) ) {
  print ("$year $month $day\n");
}else{
  print "no match\n";
}
```

~

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you can use `split()` to do what you ask for. But I wonder if what you're asking for is really the best approach.

I don't know why you want three different variables, but would suggest that when you have a date and you want to access different parts of it, then it's usually a better idea to create an object.

```
use Time::Piece;

my $date = Time::Piece->strptime('2019-08-20');
```

You can then get the individual elements that you want;

```
say $date->year;
say $date->mon;
say $date->mday;
```

But you can also get other potentially useful things:

```
say $date->month; # August
say $date->day;   # Tuesday
```

Or you could use `strftime()` to reformat the date:

```
say $date->strftime('%A, %d %B %Y'); # Monday, 20 August 2019
```

There's a lot more you can do with [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function to get three values from the input. [As mentioned in the comment ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)

```
my $str = '2019-08-20';

my ($year, $month, $day) = split /-/, $str;

print "$year\n$month\n$day\n";
```

Thanks